# Only on 404 page, get notice: trying to get property of non-object on nonce

Tags: errors, 404-error

I am using a WordPress plugin. Everything work fine. Exect when open a 404 page, I got this notice:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\MYWEB\InstantWP_4.3.1\iwpserver\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\sama-author-review\user-rate.php on line 49

Line 49 looks like this:

```
'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-user-rate-nonce-'. $post->ID)
```

Here the code:

```
/**
 * enqueue scripts used in frontend
 *
 */
function sama_enqueue_scripts() {
    global $post, $sama_author_review;

    $ajax_vars = array(
        'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-user-rate-nonce-'. $post->ID)
    );
    // see author-review.php
    wp_localize_script( 'review', 'ajax_user_rate', $ajax_vars );
}
```

Is there a quick fix to resolve these error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$post` global is not set on `404` pages, which leads to the error you are getting.

You can either check if

- `$post` is set or
- bail if the current page is a 404 page or
- do all of the above

### EXAMPLE

```
/**
 * enqueue scripts used in frontend
 *
 */
function sama_enqueue_scripts() {
     global $post, $sama_author_review;

    if ( !isset( $post ) )
        return;

     $ajax_vars = array(
         'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
         'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-user-rate-nonce-'. $post->ID)
     );
     // see author-review.php
     wp_localize_script( 'review', 'ajax_user_rate', $ajax_vars );
}
```

or

```
/**
 * enqueue scripts used in frontend
 *
 */
function sama_enqueue_scripts() {
     global $post, $sama_author_review;

    if ( is_404() )
        return;

     $ajax_vars = array(
         'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
         'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-user-rate-nonce-'. $post->ID)
     );
     // see author-review.php
     wp_localize_script( 'review', 'ajax_user_rate', $ajax_vars );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. 1000+. I am using your first answer and everything work fine.

Comment: My pleasure, glad it works. Enjoy ;-)